# Creative synonym for follower/following

Tags: synonyms

I am building a platform that will have a similar structure to Twitter and I am tirelessly looking for something that could replace the terms for connections between users.

On Twitter the terms *"Follower"* and *"Following"* are used to describe such relationships, however, those terms were established in the Twitter ecosystem and I feel like it might not immediately be clear to users what those terms refer to. Do you have any suggestions/synonyms for terms that convey the meaning of the aforementioned words ?

In Twitter's ecosystem the term *"Following"* describes a unidirectional relationship between user A and user B, where A is interested in events of user B, but not necessarily the other way around.

The term *"Follower"* describes the inverse relationship, where user B is interested in events by user A, and not necessarily vice versa.

*Bonus question:* Can you name a term that depicts a bi-directional relationship between user A and B, where both A and B are interested in each other's events ? (Bi-directional connection).

I tried to come up with terms that seem quite... obvious ... but they might not be semantically correct.

*Followers:* **Connecters/Connected [users]**

*Following:* **Connectees (not an official english word)/Connected to**

*Bi-directional relationship:* **Connections**

While very abstract, do you think these terms would convey the intended meaning ? I ask this because English is my second language and I cannot afford to gamble on those essential terms.

Comment: @BiscuitBoy My takeaway from the duplicate is that I should use "Followers" and "Following" ("Followee" sounds like a very rarely used term and thus could potentially lead to misunderstandings), the other suggestions seem to even be more unclear than "Followers" and "Following".

Comment: 'Community' is often used for a subset of interrelating people under consideration.

Comment: @the_critic- Yes. An acceptable alternative for Following/Followers seems to be far-fetched as they both seem well-established and widely used across various social media sites.

Answer (score 1):

A bi-directional relationship could be called a *symbiotic* relationship, with each partner being a *symbiote*

> **Symbiotic:** living in symbiosis, or having an interdependent relationship:
>   *Many people feel the relationship between humans and dogs is symbiotic.*

Thinking out of the box, someone that you follow could be a *luminary*, and the followers could be called *fans*, *devotees* or *admirers*. So, *following* would be replaced by *luminaries*, and *followers* by *devotees*.

<sub>[Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/symbiotic)</sub>

Comment: +1 for the creativity, but I think especially for non-native users this would be confusing (I like the term "fans" for followers though, but then again, the counterparts (e.g. "luminary" and "symbiosis") seem disjoint/too elaborate for the terminology)

Answer (score 0):

Here are some ideas all of which follow the Twitter syntax of "-ers/-ing":

- ***watchers*** and ***watching***
- ***trackers*** and ***tracking***
- ***surveyors*** and ***surveying***
- ***observers*** and ***observing***
- ***viewers*** and ***viewing***

Regardless of what you choose, you can still use ***connections*** for those who follower a user and are followed back. I like it since it carries connotations of intimacy, as in "we made a connection".

Answer (score 0):

**Connections** is certainly clearly understood on LinkedIn which uses that term for those you have directly associated with. And Silenus gave a list that only misses "Stalker" and "Stalking" if its a dating site.... ;-)

Other bi-directional ideas might be "**Associates**", "**Collaberators**", or perhaps "**colleagues**" if it for professional associations